# How to test IE conditional comments in Google Chrome on Mac

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, conditional-comments

I am using IE conditional comments in my page in the  element.
if IE<9 then  get class "lt-ie9".

Then I am using javascript to detect this class, and if I find this class, then I am redirecting the user to a different location.

My questions is:

"How can I test this on a chrome? Is there any possibility to test if the conditional comments are working in a chrome? I tried to change the user agent in the developer tools to IE8, but this seems not to work."

Any idea?

PS: I am on a Mac, so extensions like "IETab" are not going to work.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How effective is the Chrome developer tools user-agent override at emulating other browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156904/how-effective-is-the-chrome-developer-tools-user-agent-override-at-emulating-oth) (although the wording of the questions are different, I voted to mark the question as a duplicate because 1) the answer explains why your initial attempt failed and more importantly 2) the answer provides the solution to your asked question, which is "Use IETab")

Comment: @RobW Thank you. But unfortunately I am on a Mac computer, so I can't use the IETab extension...

Answer (score 4):

The Chrome Developer tools cannot emulate Internet explorer. Windows users can install the [IE Tab Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) to get some support.

If you're on a Mac or Linux, the only way to test a site on Internet explorer is to use virtualization. [Modern.ie](http://modern.ie/) provides free downloads of virtual machines for this purpose. Instructions on setting up the environment (including the download) can be found at http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools.